# Spaces with different homotopy type

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

I want to show that the spaces $ S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ and $S^1 \times S^1 $ do not have the same homotopy type.

I calculated their homologies and cohomologies and they turn out to be equal.

So I want to employ the cup product to get the desired result, but I need a hint as to how that can be done.

Thank you!

Comment: How about $\pi_2$? That should give you different results. Also, one has an abelian fundamental group $\pi_1$, the other doesn't.

Comment: Maybe compute the cohomology rings; seems like a qual problem.

Comment: What do you know? Do you know the Künneth formula? Do you know what the cohomology ring of a wedge sum is?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Well yeah. I already got the cohomology of $S^1 \times S^1$ using Kunneth and I have the cohomology $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ as the direct sum of the cohomology of each one...My problem is that I am not quite sure how to use the cup product!

Comment: The easiest way is with fundamental groups, as suggested Arthur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Künneth formula, we have
$$
H^*(S^1 \times S^1; \Bbb Z) \cong \Lambda_\Bbb Z[\alpha, \beta],
$$
the exterior algebra on two variables, with $|\alpha| = |\beta| = 1$. This can also be shown by direct computation using simplicial homology.

By the formula for the cohomology ring of a wedge sum, we have
$$
\tilde H^*(S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2; \Bbb Z) \cong \tilde H^*(S^1; \Bbb Z) \oplus \tilde H^*(S^1; \Bbb Z) \oplus \tilde H^*(S^2; \Bbb Z).
$$

Now we can see that the cup product of the two generators of $H^1(S^1 \times S^1; \Bbb Z)$ is nontrivial, whereas the cup product of the two generators of $H^1(S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2; \Bbb Z)$ is trivial. It follows that the two spaces are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! but how do you see that the cup product of the two generators in the former group is non-trivial? (I should probably mention that I am not familiar with the notion of exterior algebra)

Comment: @Mia Consider the ring isomorphism $H^*(S^1) \otimes H^*(S^1) \to H^*(S^1 \times S^1)$. Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be the generators of the two $H^1(S^1)$ factors on the left side. The tensor $\alpha \otimes \beta$ is nonzero by algebraic considerations (the only relation we have is $\alpha^2 = \beta^2 = 0$, by the cohomology of the circle). It follows that the cup product of the two generators of $H^1(S^1 \times S^1)$ cannot be zero.

Comment: @Mia Alternatively you can compute the cup product structure of $S^1 \vee S^1$ directly via simplical homology. See example 3.7 in [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.pdf). It's actually a good idea to do such examples by hand a few times. This way you can make sure you understand the low-level details.

Comment: @AymanHourieh he asked for a HINT. Let's not keep giving answers for free.

Comment: @ChrisGerig Mia asked for a hint, got two from you and me (see the comments), and then asked for more information. This is why I posted my answer. As you can see from further comments, I think my answer matched Mia's expectations.

Comment: @ChrisGerig For free?! You can choose not to help :)

Comment: Since $S^1 \vee S^1$ is a retract of $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ we can use that to show that the cup product of the two classes in degree 1 is zero.